# counter not incrementing for RAM with built-in counter

Tags: vhdl, counter, ram, quartus

I am new to vhdl and trying create a RAM in which I first write data then I read that data. The task is supposed to be created using a FSM. I have created the behavioral code as follows along with its test bench but the counters are not incrementing and I dont get it.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity sorting is

port (
clk : in std_logic;
en  : in std_logic;
data_in  : in std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);

data_out : out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0));
end entity;

architecture bhv of sorting is 
type internal_ram is array(1 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
signal int_ram_in   : internal_ram;
signal int_ram_out  : internal_ram;

type state_type is (s0, s1, s2);    --stages is fsm
signal state, nxt_state : state_type;

signal cntr_in  : integer range 0 to 3;--unsigned(1 downto 0);  --read counter
signal cntr_out : integer range 0 to 3;-- unsigned(1 downto 0); --write counter

begin

-- fsm_loop : process(clk)
-- begin
-- if rising_edge(clk) then
    -- if (en = '1') then
        -- state <= s0;
    -- else
        -- state <= nxt_state;
    -- end if;
-- end if;
-- end process;

comp_loop : process(clk, state, en, data_in)

begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then    
    case(state) is 
        when s0 =>
                if (en = '1') then
                    cntr_in <= 0;
                    cntr_out<= 0;
                else 
                    nxt_state <= s1;
                end if;

        when s1 => --writing in internal_ram
                if (cntr_in = 3) then
                    cntr_in <= 0;--(others => '0');
                    nxt_state <= s2;
                else
                    cntr_in <= cntr_in + 1;
                    int_ram_in(cntr_in) <= data_in;
                end if;

        when s2 => --using data_in
                if (cntr_out = 3) then
                    cntr_out <= 0;--(others => '0');
                    nxt_state<= s0;
                else
                    cntr_out <= cntr_out + 1;
                    data_out <= int_ram_in(cntr_out);
                end if;

    end case;
    end if;
    end process;
end bhv;
```

The test bench used is:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity sorting_tb is
end entity sorting_tb;

architecture tb of sorting_tb is

component sorting
    port (
    clk : in std_logic;
    en  : in std_logic;
    data_in  : in std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);

    data_out : out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0)
    );
    end component;

    signal clk  : std_logic := '0';
    signal en   : std_logic := '1';
    signal data_in  : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);

    signal data_out : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);

    begin

    mapping: sorting port map(
    clk => clk,
    en  => en,
    data_in => data_in,
    data_out    => data_out);

    clock: process
    begin
       clk <= '1'; wait for 10 ns;--50MHz clk
       clk <= '0'; wait for 10 ns;
    end process;

    stimuli: process
    begin
    --1st run
    wait for 10ns;
    en <= '0';
    data_in <= "111100001111000011110000";
    wait for 20ns;
    data_in <= "111100001111000011110001";
    wait for 20ns;
    data_in <= "111100001111000011110010";
    wait for 20ns;
    data_in <= "111100001111000011110011";  
--  en <= '1';
    wait for 200ns;
    en <= '1';
    --2nd run
    wait for 20ns;
    en <= '0';
    data_in <= "001100001111000011110000";
    wait for 20ns;
    data_in <= "011100001111000011110001";
    wait for 20ns;
    data_in <= "101100001111000011110010";
    wait for 20ns;
    data_in <= "111100001111000011110011";  
--  en <= '1';
    wait for 200ns;
    en <= '1';
    end process;

end tb;
```

And the simulation that I get is this:
[image]

Comment: Elaborate on what your design should do. Why have you commented out code, that changes state? Note, that your FSM is always in S0 state.

Comment: if I do that then I get this error "Fatal error in Process comp_loop at D:/altera work/sorting/sorting.vhd line 77" i.e    "int_ram_in(cntr_in) <= data_in;"

Comment: You incorrectly combined the clocked part and the combinatorial part of a 2 process state machine into 1 process. Next state should be assigned to state in the clocked process, while next state should be determined in a combinatorial process. If you don't want a 2 process FSM, don't use a next state signal.

Comment: Your fatal error is because `type internal_ram is array(1 downto 0) ...` should have 4 elements instead of two (e.g. 0 to 3 instead of 1 downto 0). It's a bounds failure during write, cntr_in has a value range of 0 to 3. For a value of 2 cntr_in is out of the index range of int_ram_in.

Comment: @user1155120 thanks that was the problem rest #JHBonarius that is also valid point